# Eigenfunctions of the laplace on the 2-sphere with conformal metric induced by schwarzschild

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mg.metric-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Hi,

it's well known that the coordinates $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are the first three eigenfunctions with positiv eigenvalues ($=2/r^2$) of the negative laplace-beltrami operator ${-}\triangle$ on the 2-dimensional $r$-sphere $M:=\mathcal S^2_r=\lbrace x\in\mathbb R^3 : \vert x\vert = r\rbrace$ as submanifold of $\overline M:=\mathbb R^3$ with regard to the metric $\eta_{pq}$ induced by the euclidean metric $\bar\delta_{ij}$ on $\overline M$. If we replace the euclidean metric $\bar\delta_{ij}$ with the Schwarzschild metric
$$\bar g_{ij}:=\Psi^4 \delta_{ij}, \qquad\Psi:\mathbb R^3\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace\to\mathbb R : x\mapsto 1+\frac m{2\cdot\vert x\vert},$$
where $m\in\mathbb R$ is the (positiv) mass, then we get the equivant result for the **concentric** spheres - with eigenvalue $2/r^2 \cdot \Psi^4$.

---

#### Question:

> What are or how do I get the first three eigenfunctions of the laplace, if the $r$-sphere has center $x_0$ with $|x_0|< $ $r$, meaning $M:=\mathcal S^2_r + x_0 := \lbrace x\in\mathbb R^3 : \vert x-x_0\vert =r\rbrace$ and the metric $g_{pq}$ on $\mathcal S^2_r(x_0)$ is again induced by the Schwarzschild metric $\bar g_{ij}$.

#### Or euqivalent:

> What are or how do I get the first eigenfunctions of the laplace-beltrami operator on the euclidean $r$-sphere $\mathcal S^2_r$ with regard to the sphere-metric $g_{pq}$ induced by the metric
> $$ \bar g_{ij} := \Psi_{x_0}^4\delta_{ij}, \qquad \Psi_{x_0}:\mathbb R^3\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace\to\mathbb R : x\mapsto 1+\frac m{2\cdot\vert x-x_0\vert}, $$
> where $x_0\in\mathbb R^3$ with $|x_0| < r$ and $m\in\mathbb R_{>0}$.

Thx for some hints

Elgrimm

Comment: You *do* know that there's no particular reason for the first positive eigenvalue to have multiplicity $3$ (or even more than $1$) on non-round $2$-spheres, right?  I.e., it could well happen (and often does), that the first positive eigenvalue has multiplicity equal $1$ and, in the case of a surface of revolution, the corresponding eigenfunction will also be invariant under the rotational isometry, so that it will be described by a solution to an ODE.

Comment: Sure your're right: The first three eigenvalues are not necessarily equal. Because of the symmetry regarding rotation around the axis spanned by $x_0$ I wouldn't be surprised, if two of the first three eigenvalues have to be equal and the third can't be (except for $x_0=0$) - but I'm not sure about this. For my current work I need all eigenfunctions with eigenvalues $\lambda$ with $\vert \lambda−2/r^2 \vert\le C/r^3$, where $C$ is a constant depending on m and $\vert x_0\vert/r$ and I would be surprised, if there are more than in the concentric case (without currently knowing it).

Comment: If I remember correctly (I don't have access to the sources right now) it is known that, if the first positive eigenvalue of the Laplacian on the $2$-sphere has multiplicity at least $3$, then the metric has to have constant Gauss curvature.  In the rotationally symmetric case, any non-rotationally symmetric eigenfunction belongs to an eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $2$, so you'd certainly expect that the lowest three would have a pair of eigenvalues equal.  (That's not guaranteed, of course, but probably is true when $|x_0|$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: Thx.

If $\vert x_0\vert/r\le\eta<1$, then$${-}\int\triangle^gf\cdot fd\mu=\int g(\nabla f,\nabla f)d\mu=\int Df\cdot Df\ dS={-}\int\triangle f\cdot f\ dS$$where $g$ is as in "equivalent", $\nabla f,\triangle^gf,d\mu$ resp. $Df,\triangle f,dS$ are the gradient, laplace and volume with respect to $g$ resp. $\delta$. With$$1+\frac m{(1+\eta)r}\le\Psi\le1+\frac m{(1-\eta)r}$$we conclude$$\left|\frac{\int f^2d\mu}{\int f^2 dS}-1\right|\le\frac{C(m,\eta)}r.$$In particular the first 3 eigenvalues are $2/r^2+\mathcal O(r^{-3})$ and the others are $>3/r^2$, as claimed in my last comment. Am I wrong?